# A better way to retrieve EF data and collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

So I have a model that contains a list of models which contains items, and so on, like this:

```
public partial class CART
{

    public CART()
    {
        //this.CART_DETAIL = new HashSet<CART_DETAIL>();
        this.CART_DETAIL = new List<CART_DETAIL>();
    }

    public int CART_IDE { get; set; }
    public int CART_COUNT { get; set; }
    public string SHOPPING_CART_IDE { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<CART_DETAIL> CART_DETAIL { get; set; }

}

public partial class CART_DETAIL
{
    public int CART_DETAIL_IDE { get; set; }
    public int CART_IDE { get; set; }
    public int CART_DETAIL_COUNT { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PACK_IDE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BACKSTORE_INVENTORY_IDE { get; set; }

    public virtual CART CART { get; set; }
    public virtual PACK PACK { get; set; }
    public virtual BACKSTORE_INVENTORY BACKSTORE_INVENTORY { get; set; }
}

public partial class BACKSTORE_INVENTORY
{
    public BACKSTORE_INVENTORY()
    {
        this.CART_DETAIL = new HashSet<CART_DETAIL>();
        this.ORDER_DETAIL = new HashSet<ORDER_DETAIL>();
    }

    public int BACKSTORE_INVENTORY_IDE { get; set; }
    public int INVENT_IDE { get; set; }
    public int STORE_IDE { get; set; }
    public decimal BACKSTORE_INVENTORY_PRICE { get; set; }
    public int BACKSTORE_STOCK_QTY { get; set; }
    public decimal BACKSTORE_DISCOUNT { get; set; }
    public decimal BACKSTORE_SELLING_PRICE { get; set; }

    public virtual INVENTORY INVENTORY { get; set; }
    public virtual STORE STORE { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CART_DETAIL> CART_DETAIL { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ORDER_DETAIL> ORDER_DETAIL { get; set; }
}
```

When I open a connection and consult the data, everything's fine, but if I retrive the whole data in a view, for example, unless I modify the `Hashset` to a `List` and then proceed like this:

```
CART cart =
                    db.CART.FirstOrDefault(_item => _item.SHOPPING_CART_IDE == mShoppingCartID && _item.CART_ACTIVE_INDICATOR);

if (cart != null)
{
    cart.CART_EXP_TIME = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(90);

    cart.USER_SESSION_IDE = UserSessionManager.GetUserSession().mUserSessionID;

    cart.CART_DETAIL = cart.CART_DETAIL.ToList();

    foreach (var cartDetail in cart.CART_DETAIL)
    {
        if(cartDetail.BACKSTORE_INVENTORY_IDE != null)
        {
            cartDetail.BACKSTORE_INVENTORY =
                db.BACKSTORE_INVENTORY.First(_item => _item.BACKSTORE_INVENTORY_IDE == cartDetail.BACKSTORE_INVENTORY_IDE);

            cartDetail.BACKSTORE_INVENTORY.INVENTORY =
                db.INVENTORY.Find(cartDetail.BACKSTORE_INVENTORY.INVENT_IDE);

            cartDetail.BACKSTORE_INVENTORY.INVENTORY.CARD =
                db.CARD.Find(cartDetail.BACKSTORE_INVENTORY.INVENTORY.CARD_IDE);
        }
        else
        {
            cartDetail.PACK = db.PACK.First(_item => _item.PACK_IDE == cartDetail.PACK_IDE);
        }
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I get the following error: `CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MyApp.Models.DAL.Entities.CART_DETAIL>'` which I understand is because the ICollection does not afford indexing, and then I get `The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.` for items that I forgot to retrive.

So my question: what makes this happen? Is there a way to retrieve all the data at once without having to get all specific items separately? A better way to do things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve form the above code?

I am struggling to follow what your end goal is but would something along these lines be what you are looking for:

```
  public List<Cart> GetAllInCart()
  {
     return db.CART.Where(a => a.Cart_IDE == CartIDE)
                   .Include(x => x.Cart_Detail)
                   .Include(x => x.Cart_Detail.Pack)
                   .Include(x => x.Cart_Detail.Backstore_Inventory)
                   .ToList()
  }
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: This helps, and not in the same time. The problem is rather that I would like to know, since I'm working with entity framework, all to retrieve all the data connected to my cart detail and keep it after my database connection is closed instead of having to get each of them individually first.

Comment: Try turning off lazy loading before the linq query. E.g db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; That should return ALL data and you should be able to remove the includes :)

Comment: Ok, how can I do that?

Comment: Well I have turned off lazy loading, but now the collections and items connected via Foreign keys does not load. In the upper example, a `BACKSTORE_INVENTORY` would be null.

Comment: I have actually just come aboard that very same issue, I misunderstood  slightly how lazy loading and eager loading work. There is NO work around for the exact issue. However Do you use a repository? If you implement a repository it means you only need to specify the includes once and just re-use the method :) Hope it helps, if you do find a suitable solution please let me know. Thanks.